# elapsed time in visual c++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this is what i did:

```
CTime startTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

// ... perform time-consuming task ...

CTime endTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

CTimeSpan elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
```

This is [the example given on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swwt5edh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But it doesn't work. VS IDE underlines the CTime in red. saying that the identifier CTime undefined.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zb0ese%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you need to `#include <atltime.h>`. Did you?

Comment: Or what is exact type of project you have in MSDEV?

Comment: @rkosegi i do not understand your question

Comment: [CTimeSpan::Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/55ba0bd5(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @klijo: The very next article after the one you saw is [Formatting Time Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cfa9ce.aspx).  But I recommend you forget you ever saw `CTime` and `CTimeSpan`, and learn to use the standard instead of an MFC-specific approach.

Comment: @klijo when you create project in MS Visual C++ what you select? Console/MFC/ATL ....

Comment: Better use sequence of `GetTickCount`/`GetTickCount64` functions.